# cmake is not able to properly read paths from windows's unix-like shells

Tags: windows, unix, cmake, mingw, msys2

I followed [llvm-clang install instructions](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) but having issues with `configure` command line. I tried both MSYS2 64 bit and Windows mingw for the purpose but similar issues appear: cmake seems confusing between windows and unix paths.

Thus, when I try MSYS2 the following error message is thrown:

> File /d/mylib/llvm/D:/mylib/llvm/utils/llvm-build/llvmbuild/main.py does not exist.

It seems that prefix `/d/mylib/llvm/` is wrongly added to the path. Note that in this case am using cmake installed with `pacman -S cmake`

On the other hand, when using windows mingw64 (that comes with git windows), am getting this error

> CMake Error: File /d/mylib/llvm/utils/TableGen/LLVMBuild.txt does not exist

though the path is correct...  Note that I in this case am using cmake installed directly on windows (using windows gui).

Any ideas please?

Comment: have you tried using a windows command shell?

Comment: no, am using only mignw or msys shell.

Comment: well... try the windows shell... :)

Comment: The error occurs in step 7 with "cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm", right?

Comment: @usr1234567 Yes. Tried again and now have this message: `CMake Error at D:/WORKSPACE/mylibs/MSYS2/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindSubversion.cmake:99 (message):
  Command "D:/WORKSPACE/mylibs/MSYS2/msys64/usr/bin/svn.exe info
  D:/WORKSPACE/mylibs/LLVM-src/llvm" failed with output:

  svn: E155007:
  '/d/WORKSPACE/mylibs/LLVM-src/build/D:/WORKSPACE/mylibs/LLVM-src/llvm' is
  not a working copy
`